# Small sample size for a regression marketing model

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I have sales, advertising spend and price data for 10 brands of same industry from 2013-2018. I want to develop an equation to predict 2019 sales.

The variables I have are (price & ad spend by type) :PricePerUnit   Magazine, News, Outdoor, Broadcasting, Print.

The confusion I have is I am not sure whether to run regression using only 2018 data with 2018 sales as Target variable and adding additional variable like Past_2Yeas_Sales(2016-17) to above price & ad spend variables (For clarity-Refer the image of data). With this type of data I will have a sample size of only 10 as there are only 10 brands. This I think is too low for linear regression to give correct results.

Second option (which will increase sample size) I figure is could be instead of having a brand as an observation, I take brand+year as an observation which will increase my sample size to 60- for e.g. Brand A has 6 observations like A-2013, A-2014, A-2014...,A-2018, B has B-2013,B-2014..B-2018 and so on for 10 brands(Refer image for data).

Is the second option valid way to run regression? What is the right way to run regression in such situations of small sample size?

[image: First option image]
[image: Second option image]

Comment: Is this school work?

Comment: @JamesPhillips No it isn't school work however this is not real data. I intend to use the learning from this dataset to implement marketing mix regression model at my workplace.

Often real sales data we have is scarce/sample size is very less so need to know how to use regression in such a scenario.

Comment: Understood - good answer.